# Python mysql print to plain text

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

I'm currently trying to print info from a MySQL database to the console, but it keeps printing it in a tuple instead of plain text. Does anyone have a solution for this?

My code:

```py
sql = "SELECT stream_time FROM schedule_cet WHERE cet_day = 'monday'"
c.execute(sql)
monday_cet = c.fetchone()
print(monday_cet)
```

I've already tried the `re` library and replace doesn't work in tuples.

Comment: `"".join(monday_cet)` concatenates a tuple to a string. `monday_cet[0]` takes the first element out of a tuple, if that's a string then you can use regex on it.

Comment: `monday_cet[0]` gives you your value out of the tuple.

Comment: Thank you khelwood! It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a mysql cursor return values as a tuple, as the query may return multiple fields

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM xx
(1, 2, 3)

SELECT a FROM xx
(1, )
```

If you use `fetchall` you'll have a list of tuples. You can have `dict` instead of tuple, by using `as_dictionary=True` when gettig the cursor, you'll get results as `{"stream_time" : "XX"}`

---

You just need to access the first item

```
print(monday_cet[0])

# or unpack it
monday_cet, = c.fetchone()
print(monday_cet)
```